# Calling a python script which has input Fields

Tags: python

I am writing a Python script that has to call a second python script which has input fields.
 The normal way to call the second script in Linux command window is:

```
python 2ndpythonscript.py input_variable output_variable
```

Now, I want to call this script from inside the first script. How do I do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use subprocess.check_call, any non-zero exit status will raise an error:

```
from subprocess import check_call

check_call(["python", "2ndpythonscript.py" ,"input_variable" ,"output_variable"])
```

Or check_output if you want to get the output:

```
from subprocess import check_output

out  = check_output(["python", "2ndpythonscript.py" ,"input_variable" ,"output_variable"])
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module, e.g.:

```
import subprocess
retcode = subprocess.call(['python', '2ndpythonscript.py', 'input_variable', 'output_variable'])
```

There are different specialized functions in the module which you can use if you want only the return code, only the output, both, stdout/stderr redirected in custom pipes and so on.